# Display a data according to the choice of several menus in cascade (Google Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu

I am developing a tool that allows to collect requests via a form created on Google Script.

The user selects via cascading drop-down menus the site, the area, the zone and finally the room for which he wants to make his request.
I would like to be able to display the manager who corresponds to the selected room but I can't. There shouldn't be much to change but I can only display in relation to the selected area.

Here are the different codes used:

- server side code :

  ```
  function getQtyOnHand(site, secteur, zone, salle){
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Table");
    const data = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 7).getValues();
    var filtre = {};
    const filteredData = data.filter(r => r[0] === site && r[1] === secteur && r[2] === zone && r[4] === salle);
    filtre.filtreSecteur = filteredData.length === 0 ? 0 : filteredData.reduce((subtotal, r) => subtotal + r[6],"");
    return filtre;
  }
  ```
- the code's functions on the front side

  ```
  function updatedQtyOnHand(){
   var site = document.getElementById("item-site").value;
   var secteur = document.getElementById("item-secteur").value;        
   var zone = document.getElementById("item-zone").value;        
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterQtyOnHandReturned).getQtyOnHand(site,secteur,zone);  
  }

  function afterQtyOnHandReturned(qty){
    document.getElementById("on-hand").textContent = ""; 
    var responsable = qty.filtreSecteur.split("@");
    var nomPrenomResp = responsable[0];
    var adresseResponsable = nomPrenomResp+"@test.com";    
    document.getElementById("on-hand").textContent = adresseResponsable; 
  }
  ```
- the html's code on the front side to show responsable (sorry for the indentation but every time I publish here, I have to redo it with spaces and I'm struggling):

  ```
  <!-- HTML DU FORMULAIRE  -->
  <div id="userform" class="userForm">
    <h1 class="mb-5" id="titreFormulaire">FORMULAIRE DEMANDE TRAVAUX NEUFS</h1>
    <div class="row mt-5 ml-3 mr-3">
    <!-- Sélection du lieu -->
      <div class="blocEndroitFull">
        <!-- Choix du site -->
        <div class ="blocEndroit">
          <label for="item-site" id="labelSite">Site :</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="item-site">
          </select>
        </div>
        <!-- Choix du secteur -->
        <div class ="blocEndroit">
          <label for="item-secteur" id="labelSecteur">Secteur :</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="item-secteur">
          </select>
        </div>
        <!-- Choix de la zone -->
        <div class ="blocEndroit">
          <label for="item-zone" id="labelZone">Désignation zone :</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="item-zone">
          </select>
        </div>
        <!-- Choix de la salle -->
        <div class ="blocEndroit">
          <label for="item-salle" id="labelSalle">Salle :</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="item-salle"> 
          </select>
        </div>
     </div> 
     <!-- Affichage du responsable -->
     <div id="responsable">
       <span class="input-group-text" id="txt-responsable">Responsable :
         <span  class="ml-1">
           <span id="on-hand"></span>
         </span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <!-- Plan -->
    <div class="col-12">
      <img id="image" width="80%" class ="rounded mx-auto d-block image">
    </div>
    <!-- Description -->
    <hr width="100%" color="black">
    <div class="form-group" id="descriptionBloc">
      <label for="delivery-note"><b>Veuillez décrire votre demande en quelques mots :</b></label>
      <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="delivery-note" rows="5" cols="100" required></textarea>  
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Décrivez votre demande</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Informations complémentaires (checklists) -->
    <div id="infoComplementairesFull">
      <div class="blocInfos">
       <label for="date-received"><b>Délai :</b></label>
       <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio" id="trimestre" value="trimestre" required>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="trimestre">Trimestre</label>
       </div>
       <div class="form-check">
         <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio" id="semestre" value="semestre">
         <label class="form-check-label" for="semestre">Semestre</label>
         <div class="invalid-feedback">Choisissez un délai.</div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="blocInfos">
       <label for="item-inter"><b>Intervention possible en production :</b></label>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio2" id="interOui" value="oui">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="interOui">Oui</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio2" id="interNon" value="non" checked>
          <label class="form-check-label" for="interNon">Non</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="blocInfos">
        <label for="item-dispo"><b>Disponibilité de la zone :</b></label>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio3" id="dispoNon" value="zone toujours disponible">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="dispoNon">Zone toujours disponible</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio3" id="dispoOui" value="travaux à planifier" checked>
          <label class="form-check-label" for="dispoOui">Travaux à planifier</label>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="blocInfos">
     <label><b>Budget est-il prévu ?</b></label>
     <div class="form-check">
       <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio4" id="budgetNon" value="non">
       <label class="form-check-label" for="budgetNon">
        Non
       </label>
     </div>
     <div class="form-check">
       <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio4" id="budgetNeSaitPas" value="ne sait pas" checked>
       <label class="form-check-label" for="budgetNeSaitPas">
        Ne sait pas
       </label>
     </div>
     <div class="form-check">
       <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio4" id="budgetOui" value="oui">
       <label class="form-check-label" for="budgetOui">
        Oui
       </label>
     </div> 
     <div id="idBudget" class="input-group input-line mb-1 d-none">
       <input id="inputIdBudget" list="listeBudget" name="radio4" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ID budget ...">
     </div>
   </div>
  ```

  **Choisissez une photo de près :**
         
         Choisissez une photo de près
       
       
         **Choisissez une photo de loin :**
         
         Choisissez une photo de loin
       
    
    
    
    
      
        Envoyer Demande
      
    
    
    
      
        
          
            Confirmation
            
              ×

- the link to the Sheet file if you want to look at it by yourself :
  [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y2x2a5LTzA67YhK5RPO3smrUaiNPAcujUBw2ULdG-cg/edit?usp=sharing)
- a screenshot of the form:
  [image]

I tried the code below but it doesn't work and I don't understand why

- server side code :

  ```
  function getQtyOnHand(site, secteur, zone, salle){
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Table");
    const data = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 7).getValues();
    var filtre = {};
    const filteredData = data.filter(r => r[0] === site && r[1] === secteur && r[2] === zone && r[4] === salle);
    filtre.filtreSecteur = filteredData.length === 0 ? 0 : filteredData.reduce((subtotal, r) => subtotal + r[6],"");
    return filtre;
  }
  ```
- the code's function on the front side :

  ```
  function updatedQtyOnHand(){
  var site = document.getElementById("item-site").value;
  var secteur = document.getElementById("item-secteur").value;        
  var zone = document.getElementById("item-zone").value;        
  var zone = document.getElementById("item-salle").value;        
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterQtyOnHandReturned).getQtyOnHand(site,secteur,zone,salle);  
  }
  ```
- the code's function where i used updatedQtyOnHand's function (in dropdown's menus:

  ```
   function afterDropDownArrayReturned(arrayOfArrays){
     arrayOfValues = arrayOfArrays.filter(function(r){ return true; });
    var item = document.getElementById("item-site");
    addUniqueOptionsToDropdownList(item,arrayOfValues,0);
    afterFirstDropDownChanged();
    afterSecondDropDownChanged();
    afterThirdDropDownChanged();
   }
   function addUniqueOptionsToDropdownList(el,arrayOfArrays,index){
     var currentlyAdded = [];
     el.innerHTML = '';
     arrayOfArrays.forEach(function(r){
       if(currentlyAdded.indexOf(r[index]) === -1){
         var option = document.createElement("option");
         option.textContent = r[index];
         el.appendChild(option);
         currentlyAdded.push(r[index]);
       }
     });
     var option = document.createElement("option");
     option.textContent = "Non défini";
     el.appendChild(option);
   }
   function afterFirstDropDownChanged(){
     var itemSecteur = document.getElementById("item-secteur");
     var secteur = document.getElementById("item-site").value;
     var filteredArrayOfValues = arrayOfValues.filter(function(r){ return r[0] === secteur });
  addUniqueOptionsToDropdownList(itemSecteur,filteredArrayOfValues,1);
  afterSecondDropDownChanged();
  updatedQtyOnHand();
  } 

   function afterSecondDropDownChanged(){

     var itemZone = document.getElementById("item-zone");
     var site = document.getElementById("item-site").value;
     var itemSecteur = document.getElementById("item-secteur").value;
     var filteredArrayOfValues = arrayOfValues.filter(function(r){ return r[0] === site && r[1] === itemSecteur});
  addUniqueOptionsToDropdownList(itemZone,filteredArrayOfValues,2);
  updatedQtyOnHand();
    }

   function afterThirdDropDownChanged(){
     var itemZone = document.getElementById("item-zone").value;
     var site = document.getElementById("item-site").value;
     var itemSecteur = document.getElementById("item-secteur").value;
     var itemSalle = document.getElementById("item-salle");
     var filteredArrayOfValues = arrayOfValues.filter(function(r){ return r[0] === site && r[1] === itemSecteur && r[2] === itemZone});
  addUniqueOptionsToDropdownList(itemSalle,filteredArrayOfValues,4);
  updatedQtyOnHand();
     }
  ```

Thanks in advance for your help and sorry for my poor English.

Comment: This website skip always my first sentence "Hello everyone,
I am developing a tool that allows to collect requests via a form created on Google Script." sorry about that

Comment: Is the "Front Side " a web app or dialog?

Comment: Could you share the complete html of the image you link?

Comment: Cooper, this is a part of a Web app. I cant publish all of the code because it's more than 1500 rows.

Comment: Nikoo, i edited my request, you can see it now

Comment: @Damien - Where did you use the `updatedQtyOnHand()` function? Also, the imports for styling are missing. I would suggest you create a new html file that will show only the drop downs and the manager text box along with the front end functions and imports for styling. You will have a complete but shorter code that focuses only on the issue and the community can easily replicate your code. See [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Nikko, i trie to reduce my code but each time i wanna delete on function, my web app didn't work. I'm not a professional developer with this and it's not easy for me. Sorry about that. I edited my first post and add functions who i use updatedQtyOnHand() function

Comment: @Damien - The part where you source the value for the drop downs are missing. Also where did you use `afterDropDownArrayReturned()`? Do you have event handler in your HTML that will execute the function in your <script>?

Comment: Bonjour Damien, dommage que tu ne puisses pas reproduire un exemple simplifié [I regret that you cannot reproduce a simplified example] https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, maybe your spreadsheet is way too complex. However, I will focus until tomorrow on a basic solution to replicate a drop-down dependent solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I committed yesterday, here is a html template focused on dependent cascading dropdown (4 levels) with sources fetched from google sheet.

On gs side:

```
function transfertHeaders() {
  var bdd = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('DB')
  return JSON.stringify(bdd.getRange(1,1,1,bdd.getLastColumn()).getValues())
}
function transfertData() {
  var bdd = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('DB')
  return JSON.stringify(bdd.getRange(2,1,bdd.getLastRow(),bdd.getLastColumn()).getValues())
}
```

on html side:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    <? 
      var headers = JSON.parse(transfertHeaders());
    ?>
    var data = JSON.parse(<?=transfertData()?>);
    
    window.onload = function() {
      var level1sel = document.getElementById("level1");
      var level2sel = document.getElementById("level2");
      var level3sel = document.getElementById("level3");
      var level4sel = document.getElementById("level4");
      var dico = new Map()

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        dico.set(data[i][0],"")
      }
      dico.forEach(function(value, key) {
        level1sel.options[level1sel.options.length] = new Option(key, key);
      })

      level1sel.onchange = function(){
        level2sel.length = 1;
        level3sel.length = 1;
        level4sel.length = 1;
        dico.clear()
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          if (data[i][0]==this.value) {dico.set(data[i][1],"")}
        }
        dico.forEach(function(value, key) {
          level2sel.options[level2sel.options.length] = new Option(key, key);
        })
      }

      level2sel.onchange = function(){
        level3sel.length = 1;
        level4sel.length = 1;
        var select1 = document.getElementById('level1');
        var value1 = select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].value;
        dico.clear()
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          if (data[i][1]==this.value && data[i][0]==value1) {dico.set(data[i][2],"")}
        }
        dico.forEach(function(value, key) {
          level3sel.options[level3sel.options.length] = new Option(key, key);
        })
      }

      level3sel.onchange = function(){
        level4sel.length = 1;
        var select1 = document.getElementById('level1');
        var value1 = select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].value;
        var select2 = document.getElementById('level2');
        var value2 = select2.options[select2.selectedIndex].value;
        dico.clear()
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          if (data[i][2]==this.value && data[i][0]==value1 && data[i][1]==value2) {dico.set(data[i][3],"")}
        }
        dico.forEach(function(value, key) {
          level4sel.options[level4sel.options.length] = new Option(key, key);
        })
      }

    }
  
  </script>
  <h3>Cascading Dropdown</h3>
  <form name="form" id="form" >
    <?!= headers[0][0] ?>: <select name="level1" id="level1">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Select <?!= headers[0][0] ?></option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <?!= headers[0][1] ?>: <select name="level2" id="level2">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Please select <?!= headers[0][0] ?> first</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <?!= headers[0][2] ?>: <select name="level3" id="level3">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Please select <?!= headers[0][1] ?> first</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <?!= headers[0][3] ?>: <select name="level4" id="level4">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Please select <?!= headers[0][2] ?> first</option>
    </select>
    <br>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

var zone
is re-defined again just after first definition. It should be salle.

Comment: Thank you Preet, it was a mistake because i "adapted" this code for share it here. But for my final project, i choose salle for the last var and its not worked. And i tried to this adapted code and its not work too